# Geoserver Custom Map on Traccar (XYZ Map Tiles)

Tags: gps, mapping, maps, geoserver, traccar

I want to generate map from geoserver to use as map for Traccar. For the map test, for example, OSM has no problems and appears normal as shown below.
[image: Traccar With OSM]

However, when I create a layer map with the geoserver and then I try to display it on Traccar, the map that appears appears repeatedly and is not as full as the map view.
[image: Traccar With Geoserver]

Did I miss something or did I make a mistake?
Please can anyone help me resolve this ?

If there is something that is still lacking from my explanation or something is still not clear, please let me know, I will be happy to explain the problem.

Comment: how did you add the map? WMTS, TMS, XYZ? what URL did you use?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question, I've looked into it and have found a solution. Previously I used a code gridset (4326) with dimensions of 2x1, so I used a code gridset (900913) with dimensions of 1x1.
I also found the use of "flipY=true" so that the position of the map that is clipped from top to bottom is correct.
so that the previous url :
'http://localhost:8090/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ne%3Aworld@EPSG%3A43263@png/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true'
Become :
'http://localhost:8090/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ne%3Aworld@EPSG%3A900913@png/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true'
And it works.

Comment: you should make that an answer and then accept it to help future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying the question. 
 I've looked into it and have found a solution. Previously I used a code gridset (4326) with dimensions of 2x1, so I used a code gridset (900913) with dimensions of 1x1. I also found the use of "flipY=true" so that the position of the map that is clipped from top to bottom is correct. 
so that the previous url : 'localhost:8090/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/…{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true'
 Become : 'localhost:8090/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/…{z}/{x}/{y}.png?flipY=true' 

And it works.